# How to solve error message " Error in if (file == "") stop("'file' must be non-empty string") : the condition has length > 1" while saving .rds?

Tags: r, r-sf

My code looks like that and works fine so far:

```
# Iterate over each row in the result
for (i in seq_along(inter2012)) {
  # Extract the indices of intersecting points for the i-th polygon
  indices <- unlist(inter2012[[i]])
  
  # Extract the corresponding polygon ID from mypolygon
  polygon_id <- mypolygon[i, "TRACTCE"]
  
  # Create a new dataset using the row values to subset mypoint2012
  new_dataset <- mypoint2012[indices, ]
  
  # Assign a name to the dataset based on the polygon ID
  dataset_name <- paste0("Crimes_2012_Census_Tract_", polygon_id)
  
  # Save the new dataset or perform other operations as needed
  assign(dataset_name, new_dataset)

}
```

It creates 1182 data frames which I want to save as .rds files. But when I adjust the code accordingly I get the error message:

> Error in if (file == "") stop("'file' must be non-empty string") : the condition has length > 1"

Here you can see the adjusted code:

```
# Iterate over each row in the result
for (i in seq_along(inter2012)) {
  # Extract the indices of intersecting points for the i-th polygon
  indices <- unlist(inter2012[[i]])
  
  # Extract the corresponding polygon ID from mypolygon
  polygon_id <- mypolygon[i, "TRACTCE"]
  
  # Create a new dataset using the row values to subset mypoint2012
  new_dataset <- mypoint2012[indices, ]
  
  # Assign a name to the dataset based on the polygon ID
  dataset_name <- paste0("Crimes_2012_Census_Tract_", polygon_id)
  
  # Save the new dataset or perform other operations as needed
  saveRDS(new_dataset, here("data_prep", paste0(dataset_name, ".rds")))

}
```

When I manually save the data frames I don't receive an error message. So far I couldn't find a solution online so I put my hope in you guys.
Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Use `traceback()` to find where the error occurs.  I'd guess it's in `saveRDS()`.  So just before calling that, print the value of `here("data_prep", paste0(dataset_name, ".rds"))`.  It appears to have more than one entry, but we don't have enough of your code to know why.

Comment: I don't know what `mypolygon` looks like, but when I'm looking at `nc` (the one used in all of the vignettes/examples for the `sf` package) and try `nc[1, "NAME"]`, it is still class `c("sf", "data.frame")`, which means that `paste0("Crimes_2012_Census_Tract_", polygon_id)` is attempting to paste a complex object (a frame) to a string. In my case, it produces `character`-vector length 2, where the first is the one that seems to be meaningful and the second is the stringification of an R object (`list(list(list(...)))`). This would be far simpler if `mypolygon` were reproducible for us.

Comment: Regardless, run your loop. When it fails, look at `polygon_id` and see if it is a `character` length one. If not, then look at _why_ it is not what it should be to be used in naming the file. My guess is that `mypolygon` is an `"sf"`-class object and `polygon_id` is also an `"sf"`-class object. Try instead `mypolygon[1,][["TRACTCE"]]` to get a single string (I'm assuming, but it is more likely in my experience).

Comment: @r2evans Thank you very much for your help. The change of the code you suggested worked out. I'm sorry that the code I provided was not sufficient, so you had to make various assumptions about the nature of my data. Nevertheless, all your assumptions were correct, chapeau. This was the first time asking a question on stackoverflow so if I'll ever ask a question again I will provide more code and data. Thank you again.